# Creating commands with a TeX `for` loop

Tags: tex-core, loops

I am trying to create many different commands based on a single command (essentially a custom header) in a predictable way. Is there a way to do this in TeX/LaTeX?

## My specific example:

I'm writing a module specification, where each of the sub headings is denoted by `\modulespec{description}{the description}` or `\modulespec{learning outcomes}{the learning outcomes}` etc. I am hoping that TeX can generate commands like `\mdescription{the description}` and `\mlearningoutcomes{the learning outcomes}`

I know that in bash-like expansion combined with TeX I would write

```
for i in 'description' 'learning outcomes'
do
    \def\csname m\getRidOfSpaces{$i} \endcsname{\modulespec{$i}{#1}}
done
```

(if you'll excuse the combination of languages) where `\getRidOfSpaces` changes `learning outcomes` to `learningoutcomes`. Is this possible/feasible with TeX/LaTeX?

M(not)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% In the real thing, this definition is much more complicated
\newcommand{\modulespec}[2]{\section{#1} #2}

% The code I want in pure TeX/LaTeX
for i in 'description' 'learning outcomes'
do
    \def\csname m\getRidOfSpaces{$i} \endcsname{\modulespec{$i}{#1}}
done
% end of non TeX code


\begin{document}

% Both work
\modulespec{description}{\blindtext}
\modulespec{learning outcomes}{\blindtext}

% These two commands should produce the same output as the previous two
\mdescription{\blindtext}
\mlearningoutcomes{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is removing the spaces an absolute requirement? It's (marginally) easier if we don't have to

Comment: Please have a look on the `forloop` package, but I am not sure whether it allows for generation of commands inside. Please add a MWE also

Comment: @JosephWright Removing the spaces is not an absolute requirement, I think there are few enough commands to define them by hand.

Comment: @ChristianH. I'm afraid I don't know enough TeX to produce anything working. I can add a minimal document to the question if that helps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a LaTeX3 implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} % to fit in one page
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\modulespec}[2]{\section{#1} #2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definemodules}{m}
 {
  \farley_definemodules:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_farley_temp_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \farley_definemodules:n #1
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_farley_temp_tl { ##1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_farley_temp_tl { ~ } { }
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { m \l_farley_temp_tl } { \modulespec { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definemodules{
  description,
  learning outcomes
}

\begin{document}

\modulespec{description}{\blindtext}
\modulespec{learning outcomes}{\blindtext}

% These two commands should produce the same output as the previous two
\mdescription{\blindtext}
\mlearningoutcomes{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments on the code.

We define a user level macro for defining all modules in one swoop; this is `\definemodules` that simply hands control to the programmer's level function `\farley_definemodules:n` (this is the best practice according to LaTeX3 programming guidelines).

Now the function `\farley_definemodules:n` splits its argument at commas and does a loop over the items. The current item is available as `#1`, but we need `##1` because we're inside a definition.

Each cycle stores the item in the scratch token list variable `\l_farley_temp_tl` so that we can apply `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` to it. The replacement is “any space is replaced by nothing”; in the programming environment spaces are ignored, so a “real space” is denoted by `~`.

Now we use the `\cs_new_protected:cpn` function that's the analog of the old style `\@namedef`: the first argument is made into a control sequence name with `\csname...\endcsname` (the token list is expanded here by TeX rule).

Comment: This is impressive! Could you explain a little how the code logic works? I've never seen anything like this before.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to do a 'for each' loop. The LaTeX kernel has a macro `\@for` which does this for each element of a comma-separated list. You also need `\zap@space` or similar to remove spaces. For example:

```
\newcommand{\modulespec}[2]{\section{#1} #2}
\makeatletter
\@for\@tempa:=description,learning outcomes\do{%
  \edef\@tempa
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\zap@space
      \expandafter\@tempa\space\@empty}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname m\@tempa\endcsname
    {\noexpand\modulespec{\@tempa}}%
}
\makeatother
```

will define `\mdescription` and `\mlearningoutcomes` as required. I've used an `\edef` to force expansion of the variable in the correct places. (No use applying `\protected@edef` here as the 'text' has to be 'safe' inside `\csname`.)

Comment: It would be good if the title remained with the two words separated. I think one possible way is by `\let\@tempb\@tempa` at the start and then putting `\modulespec{\@tempb}` instead?

Comment: @NathanaelFarley If you use two separate words you can't easily them as a document-level command

Answer (score 3):

Using `\xintFor` and the LaTeX2e kernel utilities (with an `@` in their names):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xinttools}
% In the real thing, this definition is much more complicated
\newcommand{\modulespec}[2]{\section{#1} #2}

% % The code I want in pure TeX/LaTeX
% for i in 'description' 'learning outcomes'
% do
%     \def\csname m\getRidOfSpaces{$i} \endcsname{\modulespec{$i}{#1}}
% done
% % end of non TeX code

% Nota bene: in the above you probably meant \long\def, not \def
\makeatletter
\xintFor #1 in {description, learning outcomes}\do
{\long\@namedef{m\zap@space #1 \@empty}##1{\modulespec{#1}{##1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Both work
\modulespec{description}{\blindtext}
\modulespec{learning outcomes}{\blindtext}

% These two commands should produce the same output as the previous two
\mdescription{\blindtext}
\mlearningoutcomes{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image: def loop]

Comment: the `\long\@namedef` is not quite a `\newcommand` as it doesn't check for preexisting command name.